# Do apps downloaded from App World share projects?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-world

My company creates multiple BlackBerry apps that all use a few shared Java projects.  Recently we've been chasing a bug that we theorize may be caused by an app using an old version of one of the projects.  My question is, do two apps downloaded separately from App World share the projects they have in common, or does each app use its own copy of the project?

For example, say I have two apps, Foo and Bar, which each use the project Baz.  I first download:

- Foo 1.0

  - with Baz 1.0

Then I download:

- Bar 2.0

  - with Baz 2.0

Will Bar use version 1.0 or 2.0 of Baz when I launch it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, the last-installed application's library will overwrite the existing library, which is often not what you want. This has been a longstanding problem with the BlackBerry platform, as seen [here](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Petition-to-RIM-on-review-system-please-sign/td-p/586697).

What I and others do is either:

1. include the source code for the library within the app itself, or
2. include the version number in the library

Essentially you're doing away with the concept of a shared library, which is unfortuante, but at least your app works independently of any other changes.

Sorry, I guess there's a third option: package the library as a separate download. But that has its own issues.

Comment: That's pretty annoying.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Do you know how RIM detects that two libraries are the same?  I thought it might be if the .cod files had the same name, but it doesn't seem to be.  Is it based on the qualified name of the package?  Does the signature key have anything to do with it?  (We use the same signature key for each of our apps.)

Comment: It's the package name. If you can build a version number into the package name then two different versions can coexist with no issues.

Comment: Thanks!  Boy, that makes things difficult.  Could you tell me a little more about how you implement your solution?  Do you manually change all the package names before a release, or is there a more clever way to do it?

Comment: It's a pain in the you-know-what to do. Best approach is usually to use preprocessing, but that may or may not be easy given your build situation. Search for examples of preprocessing.